# Browse Windows shares

Tags: networking, nautilus, windows-10

When I go in Files on my new 20.04 LTS laptop I don't see my Windows 10 PC with existing file shares.

When I enter smb://192.168.x.x I get the password required dialogue. Success!

When I enter smb://computername I get the following error:
Unable to access location
Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection refused

Why can't I see my Windows PC or access it by computer name please?